# Decomposition of a symmetric semi-definite matrix into sums of sparse symmetric semi-definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'll first provide the background.

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^N$ be decomposed into $n$ non-overlapping blocks of variables
$x^{(1)},\ldots,x^{(n)}$.
We say that $f:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is partially separable of degree $w$, that it can be written in the form of
\begin{align}
f(x)=\sum_{J\in\mathcal{J}}f_J(x),
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{J}$ is a finite collection of nonempty subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$,
$f_J$ are differential convex functions such that $f_J$ depends on blocks $x^{(i)}$
for $i\in J$, and
\begin{align}
\lvert J\rvert\le w,\forall J\in\mathcal{J}
\end{align}

My problem is to find the minimum degree of partial separability of function
$f(x)=x^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{M}x$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^N$, $\mathbf{M}\succeq\mathbf{0}$.
That is to decompose $\mathbf{M}$ into sums of sparse semi-definite matrix
$\mathbf{M}_J$, while minimizing the number of entries of $\mathbf{M}_J$ which
has the maximum number of entries for all $J\in\mathcal{J}$
\begin{align}
\min\max_{J\in\mathcal{J}}\lvert&\mathbf{M}_J\rvert_0\\
\sum_{J\in\mathcal{J}}\mathbf{M}_{J}=&\mathbf{M}\\
\mathbf{M}\succeq\mathbf{0},\mathbf{M}_J\succeq&\mathbf{0},\forall J\in\mathcal{J}
\end{align}
where $\lvert\cdot\rvert_0$ represents the number of entries in a matrix.

This nonlinear optimization problem seems very difficult.
I don't even know if there are any feasible
solutions.